# Google map embed Iframe is not working ?? 2023

Tags: google-maps, iframe, embed, virtual-tour

The embed is not showing the virtual tour its is instead showing the map of the entire world.this problem started on 10th November 2023 ,can any one give me any update in this please

[click to see the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C86JW.jpg)

is it a problem with google maps or am i doing something wrong in the embed, what is the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

you need API key:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/embedding-map

here is example

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/streetview?key=YOUR_API_KEY&location=46.414382,10.013988&heading=210&pitch=10&fov=35
```

Comment: Was this a recent change by Google Maps?